# Draw Points in drawn coordinate system

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I would like to produce a graph like I attached.[image]

I started with drawing a coordinate system and adding 3 points, to create a triangle, but the reference is not the origin of the coordinate system... How could I get the attached graph?

```
 \begin{center}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
  %Same unit length
  axis equal,
  scale=1.5,
  transform shape,
  axis lines=middle,
  axis line style={Stealth-Stealth, thick},
  xmin=-8.5,xmax=8.5,ymin=-8.5,ymax=8.5,
  xtick distance=1,
  ytick distance=1,
  xlabel=$x$,
  ylabel=$y$,
  title={},
  grid=both,
  grid style={line width=.1pt, draw=darkgray!10},
  major grid style={line width=.2pt,draw=darkgray!50},
  axis lines=middle,
  %For plot of functions domain
  domain = -8:8
  ]

\addplot[blue] {-1/2*x} node[above,pos=1] {};
\addplot[red] {2*x} node[above,pos=1] {};

\draw (10,8) node[anchor=north] {a}
  -- (13,8) node[anchor=north]{b}
  -- (18,14) node[anchor=south]{c}
  -- cycle;


\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Comment: You seem to be using packages `pgfplots` and `tkz-euclide`. Please edit your post to provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Comment: I would not use `pgfplots` for a graph like that but everything is possible. I think you should between plain Ti*k*Z and `pgfplots`.

Comment: I'm guessing you could add `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}` to the preamble. By default coordinates used for `\draw`, `\path`, `\node` inside the `axis` environment of `pgfplots` is not given in the coordinates of the `axis`. To explicitly use the axis coordinate system, use `axis cs:` as a prefix in the coordinate, e.e. `\draw (axis cs:0,0) ...`. With `compat=1.11` or higher on the other hand, `axis cs:` becomes the default, so it's not necessary to explicitly add it to the coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you seem to not know anything about Ti*k*Z yet, here's a simple solution without any fancy tricks, with straightforward commands that you may learn from. Note that this is not the best way to do that but one may start with something simple.

[image: graph in TikZ]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small]
        \draw[gray!50,very thin] (-5,-4) grid (5,4);
        \draw[thick,-latex] (-5,0) -- (5,0) node [below left] {x};
        \draw[thick,-latex] (0,-4) -- (0,4) node [below left] {y};
        
        \foreach \x in {-4,...,-1,1,2,3,4} \draw (\x,2pt) --++ (0,-4pt) node [below] {\x};
        \foreach \y in {-3,...,-1,1,2,3} \draw (2pt,\y) --++ (-4pt,0) node [left] {\y};

        \fill[cyan, fill opacity=0.5] (0,0) -- (0,2) node [right, pos=0.6, red, opacity=1] {$\Delta$x} -- (-1,2) node [above, pos=0.5, blue, opacity=1] {$\Delta$y} -- cycle;
        
        \fill[violet, fill opacity=0.5] (0,0) -- (2,0) node [below, pos=0.75, red, opacity=1] {$\Delta$x} -- (2,1) node [right, pos=0.5, blue, opacity=1] {$\Delta$y} -- cycle;
        
        \fill[red, fill opacity=0.5] (0,0) -- (-153:0.8) arc(-153:-63:0.8) node[pos=0.5, above] {90$^{\circ}$} -- cycle;
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (-5,-4) rectangle (5,4);  
            \draw[line width=1pt,olive,domain=(-5:5)] plot (\x,-2*\x);
            \node[olive, above] at (-1.4,3) {g};
            
            \draw[line width=1pt,blue!50!cyan,domain=(-5:5)] plot (\x,0.5*\x);      
            \node[blue!50!cyan, above left] at (4,2) {f};
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```